# google prediction api, java giving different result to web interface

Tags: java, api, prediction

I am using Google's prediction API. I have trained a few models and made predictions using Google's web interface. I want to make a few thousand predictions but the web interface only lets you make one prediction at a time. I have thus slightly adapted the "prediction-cmdline-sample" which is a sample for using the Java library to interface with the Google prediction API. However the results I am getting using the Java library are different to the web interface.

The code which I use to make a prediction is:

```
private static String predict(Prediction prediction, String text) throws IOException {
    Input input = new Input();
    InputInput inputInput = new InputInput();
    inputInput.setCsvInstance(Collections.<Object>singletonList(text));
    input.setInput(inputInput);
    Output output = prediction.trainedmodels().predict(PROJECT_ID, MODEL_ID, input).execute();
    return output.getOutputValue();
}
```

The method returns `0.500305` irrespective of what input I give (0.500305 is roughly the average value of the first column of the training data).

Any suggestions to fix this issue would be greatly appreciated.

If anyone knows of another way to make a few thousand predictions please also let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I found my problem: I wasn't formatting my input correctly. The code

> Collections.singletonList(text)

is incorrect for double type inputs, it is only correct for String inputs. What made it difficult to find this error is that the prediction API doesn't throw an error if incorrect inputs are given, it just returns some result.